# Why there is a difference in no. of rows when fetched from schema & phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using MySQL as database to one of my PHP project. It is very big database with more than 11,000,000 records across various tables. For some analysis, I tried to list the tables with total no. of records between 100000 AND 110000 records by using the following query,

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM `information_schema`.`tables` 
           WHERE `table_schema` = 'my_db' AND TABLE_ROWS BETWEEN 100000 AND 110000 
           ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC;
```

In the result for one of the tables, it showed '101556' as shown in the image below,
[image: By running query in the terminal]

But when I visited phpmyadmin, it shows higher value as shown in the below image,
[image: Screenshot from phpMyAdmin]

Please note that this is the only database available in my PC & I am not connected to Internet when I was checking this.
Can anyone please let me know why there is a difference in the rows count in the same table as explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a table under the InnoDB storage engine, an approximate row count is returned. Have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-doesnt-innodb-store-the-row-count. The comments in this reference give various explanations.